# Formulário html para banco de dados mysql não grava

Tags: php, html5, mysqli, formulário

Sou iniciante em PHP, e como muitos já estou cheio de dúvidas e buscando aprender na marra algumas técnicas e por ai vai, estou usando um template de um formulário que quero jogar no banco de dados, o mesmo não vai, quando clico em enviar, diz q foi com sucesso mas não grava no banco... Alguém ai pode me dar uma mãozinha? Vou postar o o código do php q deveria gravar no banco. Desde já agradeço a atenção! ; )

Código do arquivo que criei: grava_cheklist.php

```
<?php
    include "conexao.php";

    $responsavel = $_POST['responsavel'];
    $placa = $_POST['placa'];
    $veiculo = $_POST['veiculo'];
    $cor = $_POST['cor'];
    $combustivel = $_POST['combustivel'];
    $pneus = $_POST['pneus'];
    $kilometragem = $_POST['kilometragem'];
    $paradiante = $_POST['paradiante'];
    $teto = $_POST['teto'];
    $traseira = $_POST['traseira'];
    $paratraseiro = $_POST['paratraseiro'];
    $paralamad = $_POST['paralamad'];
    $paralamae = $_POST['paralamae'];
    $portam = $_POST['portam'];
    $portac = $_POST['portac'];
    $ptrasd = $_POST['ptrasd'];
    $ptrase = $_POST['ptrase'];
    $parabrisa = $_POST['parabrisa'];
    $dia = $_POST['dia'];
    $mes = $_POST['mes'];
    $ano = $_POST['ano'];
    $nome_cliente = $_POST['nome_cliente'];
    $sobrenome = $_POST['sobrenome'];
    $telefone = $_POST['telefone'];
    $bairro = $_POST['bairro'];
    $cidade = $_POST['cidade'];
    $documento = $_POST['documento'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $observacao = $_POST['observacao'];

    $result_cadastro = "INSERT INTO cadastro(responsavel, placa, veiculo, cor, combustivel, pneus, kilometragem, paradiante, teto, traseira, paratraseiro, paralamad, paralamae, portam, portac, ptrasd, ptrase, parabrisa, dia, mes, ano, nome_cliente, sobrenome, telefone, bairro, cidade, documento, email, observacao) VALUES ('$responsavel','$placa','$veiculo','$cor','$combustivel','$pneus','$kilometragem','$paradiante','$teto','$traseira','$paratraseiro','$paralamad','$paralamae','$portam','$portac','$ptrasd','$ptrase','$parabrisa','$dia','$mes','$ano','$nome_cliente','$sobrenome','$telefone','$bairro','$cidade','$documento','$email','$observacao')";
    $resultado_cadastro = mysqli_query($conn, $result_cadastro); 
    if(mysqli_affected_rows($conn) != 0){
                echo "Veiculo cadastrado com Sucesso";
            }else{
                echo "O veiculo não foi cadastrado com Sucesso.";   
     }

?>
```

---

este é o formulário:

```
            <form method="POST" action="grava_cheklist.php">
                <ul class="field-list">
                    <li>
                        <label class="form-label">
                          Responsável:
                           <span class="form-required"> * </span>
                        </label>
                        <div class="form-input">
                            <select class="form-dropdown" name="responsavel" required>
                                <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
                                <option value="André"> André </option>
                                <option value="Tibolla"> Avelino Tibolla </option>
                                <option value="Atendimento"> Atendimento </option>
                                <option value="cliente"> Cliente </option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        </li>
                  <li>
                     <label class="form-label"> 
                           Placa:
                            <span class="form-required"> * </span>
                        </label>
                        <div class="form-input">
                            <input type="text" name="placa" maxlength="7" placeholder="Entrar com a placa do carro" required >
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                     <label class="form-label"> 
                           Veículo:
                            <span class="form-required"> * </span>
                        </label>
                        <div class="form-input">
                            <input type="text" name="veiculo" maxlength="20" placeholder="Entrar com o nome do carro" required >
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label class="form-label">
                           Cor:
                           <span class="form-required"> * </span>
                        </label>
                        <div class="form-input">
                            <select class="form-dropdown" name="cor" required>
                                <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
                                <option value="Branco"> Branco </option>
                                <option value="Preto"> Preto </option>
                                <option value="Cinza"> Cinza </option>
                                <option value="Vermelho"> Vermelho </option>
                                <option value="Marrom"> Marrom </option>
                                <option value="Verde"> Verde </option>
                                <option value="Amarelo"> Amarelo </option>
                                <option value="Bordo"> Bordo </option>
                                <option value="Cinza"> Cinza </option>
                                <option value="Azul"> Azul </option>
                                <option value="outros"> Outros </option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                        <label class="form-label">
                           Combustível:
                           <span class="form-required"> * </span>
                        </label>
                        <div class="form-input">
                            <select class="form-dropdown" name="combustivel" required>
                                <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
                                <option value="reseva"> reserva </option>
                                <option value="cheio"> Cheio </option>
                                <option value="1/3"> 1/3 </option>
                                <option value="3/4"> 3/4 </option>
                                <option value="meio"> meio </option>
                                <option value="vazio"> Vazio </option>
                                <option value="outros"> Outros </option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                            </li>
                        <li>
                        <label class="form-label">
                           Pneus:
                           <span class="form-required"> * </span>
                        </label>
                        <div class="form-input">
                            <select class="form-dropdown" name="pneus" required>
                                <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
                                <option value="bons"> Bons </option>
                                <option value="ruins"> Ruins </option>
                                <option value="novos"> Novos </option>
                                <option value="outros"> Outros </option>
                            </select>
                          </div>
                       </li>
                     <li> 
                        <label class="form-label">
                           Kilometragem:
                          <span class="form-required"> * </span>
                        </label>
                        <div class="form-input">
                            <input type="text" name="kilometragem" maxlength="20" placeholder="Kilometragem" required>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label class="form-label">
                           Parachoque Diant.:
                           <span class="form-required"> * </span>
                        </label>
                        <div class="form-input">
                            <select class="form-dropdown" name="paradiante" required>
                                <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
                              <option value="OK"> OK </option>
                              <option value="Risco"> Risco </option>
                              <option value="Amassado"> Amassado </option>
                              <option value="Manchado"> Manchado </option>
                              <option value="Quebrado"> Quebrado </option>
                              <option value="Ver Nas Observações"> Ver Nas Observações </option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        </li>
                     <li>
                        <label class="form-label">
                           Teto:
                           <span class="form-required"> * </span>
                        </label>
                        <div class="form-input">
                            <select class="form-dropdown" name="teto" required>
                                <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
                                <option value="OK"> OK </option>
                                <option value="Risco"> Risco </option>
                                <option value="Amassado"> Amassado </option>
                                <option value="Manchado"> Manchado </option>
                                <option value="Quebrado"> Quebrado </option>
                                <option value="Ver Nas Observações"> Ver Nas Observações </option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                         </li>
                     <li>
                        <label class="form-label">
                           Tampa Traseira:
                           <span class="form-required"> * </span>
                        </label>
                        <div class="form-input">
                            <select class="form-dropdown" name="traseira" required>
                                <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
                                <option value="OK"> OK </option>
                                <option value="Risco"> Risco </option>
                                <option value="Amassada"> Amassada </option>
                                <option value="Manchada"> Manchada </option>
                                <option value="Quebrado"> Quebrada </option>
                                <option value="Ver Nas Observações"> Ver Nas Observações </option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                         </li>
                     <li>
                        <label class="form-label">
                           Parachoque Tras.:
                           <span class="form-required"> * </span>
                        </label>
                        <div class="form-input">
                            <select class="form-dropdown" name="paratraseiro" required>
                                <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
                                <option value="OK"> OK </option>
                                <option value="Risco"> Risco </option>
                                <option value="Amassado"> Amassado </option>
                                <option value="Manchado"> Manchado </option>
                                <option value="Quebrado"> Quebrado </option>
                                <option value="Ver Nas Observações"> Ver Nas Observações </option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                         </li>
                     <li>
                        <label class="form-label">
                           Paralama Dir.:
                           <span class="form-required"> * </span>
                        </label>
                        <div class="form-input">
                            <select class="form-dropdown" name="paralamad" required>
                                <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
                                <option value="OK"> OK </option>
                                <option value="Risco"> Risco </option>
                                <option value="Amassado"> Amassado </option>
                                <option value="Manchado"> Manchado </option>
                                <option value="Quebrado"> Quebrado </option>
                                <option value="Ver Nas Observações"> Ver Nas Observações </option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                         </li>
                     <li>
                        <label class="form-label">
                           Paralama Esq.:
                           <span class="form-required"> * </span>
                        </label>
                        <div class="form-input">
                            <select class="form-dropdown" name="paralamae" required>
                                <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
                                <option value="OK"> OK </option>
                                <option value="Risco"> Risco </option>
                                <option value="Amassado"> Amassado </option>
                                <option value="Manchado"> Manchado </option>
                                <option value="Quebrado"> Quebrado </option>
                                <option value="Ver Nas Observações"> Ver Nas Observações </option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                         </li>
                     <li>
                        <label class="form-label">
                           Porta do Motorista:
                           <span class="form-required"> * </span>
                        </label>
                        <div class="form-input">
                            <select class="form-dropdown" name="portam" required>
                                <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
                                <option value="OK"> OK </option>
                                <option value="Risco"> Risco </option>
                                <option value="Amassada"> Amassada </option>
                                <option value="Manchada"> Manchada </option>
                                <option value="Quebrada"> Quebrada </option>
                                <option value="Ver Nas Observações"> Ver Nas Observações </option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                         </li>
                      <li>
                        <label class="form-label">
                           Porta do Carona:
                           <span class="form-required"> * </span>
                        </label>
                        <div class="form-input">
                            <select class="form-dropdown" name="portac" required>
                                <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
                                <option value="OK"> OK </option>
                                <option value="Risco"> Risco </option>
                                <option value="Amassada"> Amassada </option>
                                <option value="Manchada"> Manchada </option>
                                <option value="Quebrada"> Quebrada </option>
                                <option value="Ver Nas Observações"> Ver Nas Observações </option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                          </li>
                     <li>
                        <label class="form-label">
                           Porta tras. Dir.:
                           <span class="form-required"> * </span>
                        </label>
                        <div class="form-input">
                            <select class="form-dropdown" name="ptrasd" required>
                                <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
                                <option value="OK"> OK </option>
                                <option value="Risco"> Risco </option>
                                <option value="Amassada"> Amassada </option>
                                <option value="Manchada"> Manchada </option>
                                <option value="Quebrada"> Quebrada </option>
                                <option value="Sem esta Porta"> Sem esta Porta </option>
                                <option value="Ver Nas Observações"> Ver Nas Observações </option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                         </li>
                     <li>
                        <label class="form-label">
                           Porta tras. Esq.:
                           <span class="form-required"> * </span>
                        </label>
                        <div class="form-input">
                            <select class="form-dropdown" name="ptrase" required>
                                <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
                                <option value="OK"> OK </option>
                                <option value="Risco"> Risco </option>
                                <option value="Amassada"> Amassada </option>
                                <option value="Manchada"> Manchada </option>
                                <option value="Quebrada"> Quebrada </option>
                                <option value="Sem esta Porta"> Sem esta Porta </option>
                                <option value="Ver Nas Observações"> Ver Nas Observações </option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                         </li>
                      <li>
                        <label class="form-label">
                           Parabrisa:
                           <span class="form-required"> * </span>
                        </label>
                        <div class="form-input">
                            <select class="form-dropdown" name="parabrisa" required>
                                <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
                                <option value="OK"> OK </option>
                                <option value="Risco"> Risco </option>
                                <option value="Trincado"> Trincado </option>
                                <option value="Manchado"> Manchado </option>
                                <option value="Quebrado"> Quebrado </option>
                                <option value="Ver Nas Observações"> Ver Nas Observações </option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                     <li>
                        <label class="form-label">
                           Data de Hoje:
                          <span class="form-required"> * </span>
                        </label>
                        <div class="form-input dob">
                            <span class="form-sub-label">
                                <select name="dia" class="Dia">
                                    <option>&nbsp;</option>
                                    <option value="1"> 1 </option>
                                    <option value="2"> 2 </option>
                                    <option value="3"> 3 </option>
                                    <option value="4"> 4 </option>
                                    <option value="5"> 5 </option>
                                    <option value="6"> 6 </option>
                                    <option value="7"> 7 </option>
                                    <option value="8"> 8 </option>
                                    <option value="9"> 9 </option>
                                    <option value="10"> 10 </option>
                                    <option value="11"> 11 </option>
                                    <option value="12"> 12 </option>
                                    <option value="13"> 13 </option>
                                    <option value="14"> 14 </option>
                                    <option value="15"> 15 </option>
                                    <option value="16"> 16 </option>
                                    <option value="17"> 17 </option>
                                    <option value="18"> 18 </option>
                                    <option value="19"> 19 </option>
                                    <option value="20"> 20 </option>
                                    <option value="21"> 21 </option>
                                    <option value="22"> 22 </option>
                                    <option value="23"> 23 </option>
                                    <option value="24"> 24 </option>
                                    <option value="25"> 25 </option>
                                    <option value="26"> 26 </option>
                                    <option value="27"> 27 </option>
                                    <option value="28"> 28 </option>
                                    <option value="29"> 29 </option>
                                    <option value="30"> 30 </option>
                                    <option value="31"> 31 </option>
                                </select>
                                <label class="form-sub-label1"> Dia </label>
                            </span>
                          <span class="form-sub-label">
                                <select name="mes" class="mes">
                                    <option>&nbsp;</option>
                                    <option value="Janeiro"> Janeiro </option>
                                    <option value="Fevereiro"> Fevereiro </option>
                                    <option value="Março"> Março </option>
                                    <option value="Abril"> Abril </option>
                                    <option value="Maio"> Maio </option>
                                    <option value="Junho"> Junho </option>
                                    <option value="Julho"> Julho </option>
                                    <option value="Agosto"> Agosto </option>
                                    <option value="Setembro"> Setembro </option>
                                    <option value="Outubro"> Outubro </option>
                                    <option value="Novembro"> Novembro </option>
                                    <option value="Dezembro"> Dezembro </option>
                                 </select>
                                <label class="form-sub-label1"> Mês </label>
                            </span> 
                            <span class="form-sub-label">
                                <input type="text" class="year" name="ano" size="4" maxlength="4" placeholder="Ano" required>
                                <label class="form-sub-label1"> Ano </label>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li> 
                        <label class="form-label">
                           Cliente Nome/Sobrenome:
                           <span class="form-required"> * </span>
                        </label>
                        <div class="form-input add">
                            <span class="form-sub-label">
                                <input type="text" name="nome_cliente" maxlength="50" placeholder="Nome" required>
                                <label class="form-sub-label1"> Nome </label>
                            </span>
                            <span class="form-sub-label">
                                <input type="text" name="sobrenome" maxlength="50" placeholder="Sobrenome" required>
                                <label class="form-sub-label1"> Sobrenome </label>
                            </span>
                            <span class="form-sub-label">
                                <input type="text" name="telefone" placeholder="Telefone" size="11" maxlength="11" required>
                                <label class="form-sub-label1"> Telefone </label>
                            </span>
                            <span class="form-sub-label">
                                <input type="text" name="bairro" placeholder="Bairro" maxlength="20" required>
                                <label class="form-sub-label1"> Bairro </label>
                            </span>
                            <span class="form-sub-label">
                                <input type="text" name="cidade" placeholder="Cidade" maxlength="20" required>
                                <label class="form-sub-label1"> Cidade </label>
                            </span>
                            <span class="form-sub-label">
                                <input type="text" name="documento" placeholder="Documento" size="11" maxlength="11" required>
                                <label class="form-sub-label1"> Documento </label>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li> 
                        <label class="form-label">
                           E-Mail do Cliente
                           <span class="form-required"> * </span>
                        </label>
                        <div class="form-input">
                            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="cliente@examplo.com.br" maxlength="50" required>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li> 
                        <label class="form-label1">
                            Observações do Chek-list do Veículo
                        </label>
                        <div class="form-input2">
                            <textarea rows="5" cols="20" name="observacao" maxlength="200"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="last-type"> 
                        <label class="form-label1">
                            Atesto Chek-List acima devidamente preenchido e assino o presente.<br><br>
                            Responsável: ..........................................................<br><br>
                            Cliente: ...................................................................<br><br> 
                            <span class="form-required">Cliente acompanhou e assinou o Chek-List concordando, insentando a Mecânica Tibolla de qualquer coisa que por ventura venha a ser visto posteriormente.</span>
                        </label>
                        <div class="form-input2">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="concordo" ><label class="type-of-test"></label>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                <input type="submit" name="cadastrar" value="Gravar Chek-List">
                </ul>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A probabilidade de cometer um engano com tantos campos é considerável. Aconselho a dar um `var_dump` sobre o `$result_cadastro` para perceber se a consulta está ou não correta. Pode inclusivamente executar o `mysqli_query` seguido de `or die(mysqli_error($conn));` para perceber o erro que tem, se estiver no `insert` claro

Comment: coloque o seu formulário

Comment: Primeiramente obrigado pela atenção! coloquei o "die" como sugerido e recebi a seguinte mensagem:  Notice: Use of undefined constant mysqli_query - assumed 'mysqli_query'

Comment: <label class="form-label">
Responsável:
<span class="form-required"> * </span>
</label>
<div class="form-input">
<select class="form-dropdown" name="responsavel" required>
         <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
         <option value="André"> André </option>
         <option value="Tibolla"> Avelino Tibolla </option>
         <option value="Atendimento"> Atendimento </option>
         <option value="cliente"> Cliente </option>
        </select>
       </div>
       </li>

Comment: A sua pergunta não foi removida, o que foi removido foi a resposta. Para adicionar mais detalhes a pergunta clique no botão editar ou nesse [**link**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/254802/edit)

Answer (score 0):

Bom no seu formulário a sua tag `<form>` deve estar desta forma

`<form action='grava_ckecklist.php' method='POST'>`

E seus inputs devem ter names idênticos para corresponderem aos seus POSTS, pois o `$_POST` nada mais é que uma variável que recebe o dado vindo do formulário e depois armazena numa variável para inserir no banco. Verifique se seus inputs estão assim, como no exemplo abaixo.

```
<input type='text' name='responsavel'>
<input type='text' name='placa'>
<input type='text' name='veiculo'>
```

E para que o seu `POST` seja respectivo e receber o dado vindo do formulário, deve estar idêntico aos `names` dos seus `inputs`, como no exemplo abaixo.

```
$responsavel = $_POST['responsavel'];
$placa = $_POST['placa'];
$veiculo = $_POST['veiculo'];
```

E agora vamos ao `INSERT`, fiz um teste aqui e deu certo justamente com o seu `INSERT`, portanto vou colocar abaixo também

```
$result_cadastro = "INSERT INTO cadastro (responsavel, placa, veiculo, cor, 
combustivel, pneus, kilometragem, paradiante, teto, traseira, paratraseiro, 
paralamad, paralamae, portam, portac, ptrasd, ptrase, parabrisa, dia, mes, 
ano, nome_cliente, sobrenome, telefone, bairro, cidade, documento, email, 
observacao) VALUES ('$responsavel', '$placa', '$veiculo', '$cor', 
'$combustivel', '$pneus', '$kilometragem', '$paradiante', '$teto', 
'$traseira', '$paratraseiro', '$paralamad', '$paralamae', '$portam', 
'$portac', '$ptrasd', '$ptrase', '$parabrisa', '$dia', '$mes', '$ano', 
'$nome_cliente', '$sobrenome', '$telefone', '$bairro', '$cidade', 
'$documento', '$email', '$observacao')";
```

Portanto verifique o tamanho que você colocou dos seus campos no seu banco de dados, pois se você indicou por um exemplo que o campo `responsavel` da tabela `cadastro` sera `varchar(20)`, ou seja, receberá até 20 caracteres no máximo, e está tentando inserir dados vindos do formulário com 21 caracteres apenas neste campo e os outros todos forem corretos, o `INSERT` não funcionará, então veja o tamanho dos seus campos no `Banco de Dados` e faça isso que vou indicar abaixo no seu `<input>`

Se o campo possuir uma limitação de caracteres, como vou mostrar no exemplo abaixo

```
responsavel varchar(20)
```

Adicione isto no seu input, pois irá fazer com que o campo só receba no máximo 20 caracteres, impossibilitando erros ao gravar os dados vindos do formulário

```
<input type='text' name='responsavel' maxlength='20'>
```

Se mesmo assim não conseguir ter o resultado esperado que é o seu `INSERT` no `Banco de Dados` faça isso que irei lhe mostrar abaixo, após sua variável `$resultado_cadastro` de um `echo` na variável do seu `INSERT`, como irei mostrar abaixo

```
$resultado_cadastro = mysqli_query($conn, $result_cadastro);
echo $result_cadastro;
```

Isso fará com que seja exibido os dados vindos do formulário na tela e você poderá verificar com maior clareza onde o erro esta, e se mesmo assim não enxergar copie o resultado exibido na tela e cole no seu banco de dados e ai então irá mostrar qual o erro, se você esta inserindo dados de `caracter em campo inteiro`, dados de `caracter em campo booleano`. E ai você dá um `feedback` aqui na minha resposta ae me indica o que esta acontecendo depois disso tudo que iremos resolver.

Comment: outra coisa, depois q dei um echo $result_cadastro;, apareceu na pagina grava_cheklist.php no navegador tudo q eu coloquei no formulário!!...rs Até me emocionei, mas não foi para o banco de dados..rs

Comment: então faça isso, copie tudo que apareceu que creio que seja algo parecido como INSERT INTO cadastro ...... e cole no seu banco de dados MYSQL e lá irá acusar o erro. como eu informei na resposta

Comment: Poste na sua pergunta o que aparece na tela quando da echo $result_cadastro

Comment: INSERT INTO cadastro(id,responsavel, placa, veiculo, cor, combustivel, pneus, kilometragem, paradiante, teto, traseira, paratraseiro, paralamad, paralamae, portam, portac, ptrasd, ptrase, parabrisa, dia, mes, ano, nome_cliente, sobrenome, telefone, bairro, cidade, documento, email, observacao) VALUES ('Atendimento','ilf4923','CORSA','Vermelho','reseva','bons','11111111111111111111','OK','OK','OK','OK','OK','OK','OK','OK','OK','OK','OK','13','Novembro','2017','giva','braz','00000000000','belo horizonte','caxias do sul','00000000000','teste@teste.com.br','carro esta ok')

Comment: @GivaBraz Parece que não falta aspas, seus campos são todos varchar ? Poste na pergunta clique em editar e coloque i seu formulário para eu verificar